# Refresh page after NgbModal is closed

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a component that uses an **ngbModal** to add some stuff to my data base, the problem is that when the Modal is closed and the POST action happens, I can't find a way to refresh the data displayed on my "parent page" (on the parent component I have a subscription that loads the data),

So is there any way to refresh those data dynamically after closing the modal ?

Or is there a way to bind data between two component? so that when data is changed on one, it changes on the other.

This is the button that opens a modal (`lgModalShow()`), and in this component I call for the data,

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="lgModalShow()">Modal</button>

lgModalShow() {
const activeModal = this.modalService.open(DefaultModal, {size: 'lg'});
activeModal.componentInstance.modalHeader = 'Large Modal';  
}


this.service.getData(this.url)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    },)
```

In the DefaultModal I add the new data :

```
add(): void {
this.service.create(Object)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
   },)}
```

Those are just the important snippets of the code, and the problem is that  I don't know how to refresh the data in the first component after adding it in my modal.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private location:Location) {} 

closeModal() : void {
 this.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Property 'reload' does not exist on type 'Location'.

Comment: window.location.reload(); but what if you are using angular and toastr? If you reload, the message will not be shown and the spa principle will not be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$scope.$parent.$location.reload()` in the `closeModel()` method. If you post your code of how you open and clothe model, I can help you better.